# How to read a blob in Azure databricks with SAS

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm new to Databricks. I write sample code to read Storage Blob in Azure Databricks.

```
blob_account_name = "sars"
blob_container_name = "mpi"
blob_sas_token =r"**"
ini_path = "58154388-b043-4080-a0ef-aa5fdefe22c8"

inputini = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name, ini_path)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net"% (blob_container_name, blob_account_name), blob_sas_token)

print(inputini)
ini=sc.textFile(inputini).collect()
```

It throw error:

```
Container mpi in account sars.blob.core.windows.net not found
```

I guess it doesn't attach the SAS token in WASBS link, so that it doesn't permission to read the data.

How to attach the SAS in wasbs link.

Answer (score -2):

This is excepted behaviour, you cannot access the read private storage from Databricks. In order to access private data from storage where firewall is enabled or when created in a vnet, you will have to   Deploy Azure Databricks in your Azure Virtual Network then whitelist the Vnet address range in the firewall of the storage account. You could refer to configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks.

**WITH PRIVATE ACCESS:**

When you have provided access level to "**Private (no anonymous access)**".

[image]

**Output: Error message**

> shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container carona in account cheprasas.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.

[image]

**WITH CONTAINER ACCESS:**

When you have provided access level to "**Container (Anonymous read access for containers and blobs)**".

[image]

**Output:** You will able to see the output without any issue.

[image]

**Reference:** [Quickstart: Run a Spark job on Azure Databricks using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-portal#run-a-spark-sql-job).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.